# Apparently non uniform substitution in arc length (re)parametrization ( OpenStax Calculus III)

Tags: soft-question, vector-analysis, arc-length

In the OpenStax Calculus III book ( page 287-286) , an example is given of arc length parametrization.

The original function is : $ r(t)= 4\cos(t)$**i**$+4\sin(t)$**j**.

The arc length function is : $s(t)= 4t$, implying that $t=s/4$.

Then comes the substitution : $r(s)= 4\cos(s/4)$**i**$+4\sin(s/4)$**j**.

It looks as though the substitution were not uniform. I cannot understand why on the LHS the parameter $t$ is replaced by $s$, while on the RHS, it is $s/4$ that is substituted for $t$.

Sure I'm missing something, but I cannot see what.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing anything. If that's what they wrote, it is just an abuse of notation. We are defining a new function $r_0(s):=r\left(\frac{s}{4}\right)$. They are abusing notation by calling $r_0$ and $r$ (which are completely different functions) by the same letter $r$.

Comment: I've added the screenshots.

Comment: @FloridusFloridi yes they are abusing notation (and I completely abhor such notation), but unfortunately it is common to do this. More formally, they're considering the function $\mu:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, $\mu(s)=\frac{s}{4}$. i.e $\mu$ maps the $s$ parameter to the $t$-parameter. So, $\mu$ is the change of parametrization, and $r_0=r\circ \mu$ is the reparametrized curve.